# What I can use instead of strstream::freeze?

Tags: c++

I am working on some old c++ codes and it has strstream class which is deprecated. I need to replace them with working ones.

In my header file I got this:

```
ostrstream          tokenBuff;
```

and .c file that uses header:

```
tokenBuff.freeze(0);
tokenBuff.seekp(0);
```

I replaced **ostrstream** with **ostringstream**. ostringstream has seekp() but not freeze(). How can I deal with this problem. Thanks.

Comment: _I am working on some old c++ codes_..... so why [tag:c] tag....?

Comment: Note that it's OK to keep using strstream if the code was already using it and working

Comment: Hi, it is not working. Purpose is version upgrade.

Comment: Read what [freeze](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ostrstream/freeze) does. Maybe you don't need it. If you disable dynamic allocation of buffer with `freeze`, there is a high possbility that text will be truncated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `freeze()` in case of `std::ostringstream` - the necessity of calling this function was actually one of the reasons why `strstream` got deprecated in the first place. Because of its design (returning `char*` from `str()`) it wasn't clear who should clean the buffer that `strstream` holds and `freeze()` had to be used to signal that you want `strstream` itself to do it after every call to `str()` - in case of `std::ostringstream` you don't need to worry about this as `str()` returns a copy of the `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no replacement for `freeze` in `ostringsteam` since it is no longer needed. In `ostrstream` `freeze()` is used to work around the deficiency that `str()` returns a c-style (`char *`) string.